# How do I get second level public properties in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack-autoquery

I have the following POCOs in my service model:

```
public class Personnel {
 ...

    [Ignore]
    [Reference]
    public List<Posting> _Postings { get; set; }
}

public class Posting {
    ...

    [Reference]
    [Ignore]
    public Personnel Personnel { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    [Ignore]
    public Position _Position { get; set; }
}

public class Position {
    ...

    [Reference]
    [Ignore]
    public List<Posting> _Postings { get; set; }
}
```

When I use AutoQuery RDBMS to get Personnel I want to be able to get e.g. Personnel._Postings[1]._Position.Title.

How do I get the Position object which is a second level public property to Personnel using ServiceStack AutoQuery RDBMS? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `[Ignore]` that tells [OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) and [AutoQuery](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms) to ignore the property.

AutoQuery [automatically returns nested results](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#returning-nested-related-results) but your Data Models need to follow [OrmLite's Reference Conventions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#reference-support-poco-style).